# Empty space above and below Text elements in a ColumnLayout

Tags: qt, qml

I have QML Text elements in a ColumnLayout like so:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
Item {
    Rectangle {
        ColumnLayout {
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.bottomMargin: 5
            Canvas {
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.fillWidth: true
            }
            Text {}
            Text {}
            Text {}
        }
    }
}
```

The canvas fill the top part of the column nicely and the Texts line up beneath it just fine. That anchors.bottomMargin sets a small margin only at the very bottom. But no matter what margins or anchors I set for the Texts, there is a lot of vertical empty space between them. The text is just numbers so there is no concern about characters that need to take up more room. How do I get rid of this space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've run into this issue as well, and there wasn't a solution. However, in Qt 5.4, the [FontMetrics](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qml-qtquick-fontmetrics.html) and [TextMetrics](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qml-qtquick-textmetrics.html) QML types were added.

### TextMetrics

FontMetrics has a comprehensive API which mirrors the C++ [QFontMetricsF](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfontmetricsf.html) class, with some of it being imperative (functions). TextMetrics takes the functions in FontMetrics and makes them declarative (properties) for convenience, plus some extra properties for completeness.

Given some text string, TextMetrics will provide you with the `tightBoundingRect` property, which, as its name suggests, is a tight bounding rectangle around the string, without the extra space that you normally see. Take that height from the height of a string with only numbers in it, and you get the superfluous height than can be used as negative spacing:

```
import QtQuick 2.4

Item {
    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent

        TextMetrics {
            id: metrics
            text: "1"
        }

        Column {
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.bottomMargin: 5
            spacing: -(metrics.height - metrics.tightBoundingRect.height)

            Text { text: "123" }
            Text { text: "123" }
            Text { text: "123" }
        }
    }
}
```

Note the [warning](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfontmetricsf.html#tightBoundingRect) from the documentation:

> Warning: Calling this method is very slow on Windows.

That shouldn't be a problem if you only set the text/font on the TextMetrics object once though, as it will only calculate it once.

### Line height

An alternative, but sketchy approach is to basically guess a value for the `lineHeight` property of each `Text` item.

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Column {
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.bottomMargin: 5
            Text { text: "123"; lineHeight: 0.8 }
            Text { text: "123"; lineHeight: 0.8 }
            Text { text: "123"; lineHeight: 0.8 }
        }
    }
}
```

### Negative spacing

As Shubhanga said, negative spacing will also work, but it's also not so great:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Column {
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.bottomMargin: 5
            spacing: -4
            Text { text: "123" }
            Text { text: "123" }
            Text { text: "123" }
        }
    }
}
```

### Text height

Again, mentioned by Shubhanga, setting the text's height explicitly will work, but there's still guesswork involved. Like the two solutions above, you'll have to change the value you subtract from the height each time you change font size, and it won't scale between devices (low DPI desktop PC vs high DPI mobile):

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    readonly property int heightAdjustment: 5
    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Column {
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.bottomMargin: 5
            Text {
                text: "123";
                height: implicitHeight - heightAdjustment
            }
            Text {
                text: "123";
                height: implicitHeight - heightAdjustment
            }
            Text {
                text: "123";
                height: implicitHeight - heightAdjustment
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Impressive answer, but sadly we don't use QtQuick 2.4 yet, and it seems that negative spacing triggers an ASSERT in any case.

Comment: Which Qt version are you using? What about the lineHeight solution?

Comment: I don't get any assertion with Qt 5.1.1.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the approach you're discussing with Shubhanga. Also, only the first solution is restricted to Qt Quick 2.4, so I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `spacing` property? This is used to set spacing between layout's contents. The default value is 5. Try setting it as 0.

Reference [ColumnLayout spacing property](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-columnlayout.html#spacing-prop)

Comment: That helped, by five pixels! The default spacing for _Column_ is zero, which is rather inconsistent. (The item used to be a Column, which is when I checked the docs.) However, there is still quite a bit of empty space, presumably reserved for tall/deep letters, which I don't need. Can I play with some .baseline property?

Comment: The height of the `Text` element can be set explicitly and can be reduced so that the bounding rectangle's(the invisible rectangle surrounding the text) height is less. This might solve your problem. If you post full qml code, I guess I can help.

Comment: Could you please post a snippet showing how to set Text { height } to a value that is computed, not guessed?